# If a 2D array is not a double pointer , then why does this happen?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{     
  int arr[3][4] = { 
                    { 10, 11, 12, 13 }, 
                    { 20, 21, 22, 23 }, 
                    { 30, 31, 32, 33 } 
                  }; 
  printf("%u, %u", arr, *arr) // Output - 1875181168, 1875181168

}
```

Assuming any 2D Array (arr), is not a double pointer, then why does arr & *arr refer to the same address ?

Comment: Both the beginning of `arr` and `arr[0]` exist at the same address.  Why is that unexpected?

Comment: On a side-note, to use `printf` to print (`void *`) pointers, use the `"%p"` format. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @chux - My question was around arr & *arr holding the same value, not around arr pointing to arr[0]

Comment: `arr` does not point to `arr[0]`.

Comment: @chux - Sorry, my bad. I meant the relation between arr & arr[0]. arr points to arr[0][0].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we "draw" the array `arr` on paper it will look like this

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| arr[0][0] | arr[0][1] | arr[0][2] | arr[0][3] | arr[1][0] | ... |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
```

From this it should be easy to see that pointers to the array, the first element of the array, and the first sub-element of the first element will all be the same.

That is, `&arr == &arr[0]` and `&arr[0] == &arr[0][0]` (which of course means that `&arr == &arr[0][0]`).

The differences here is the types:

- `&arr` is of the type `int (*)[3][4]`
- `&arr[0]` is of the type `int (*)[4]`
- And `&arr[0][0]` is of the type `int *`

Now as for `arr` and `*arr`, you have to remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first elements. This means `arr` will be equal to `&arr[0]`. And dereferencing a pointer will be the "value" being pointed to, so `*arr` is equal to `*(&arr[0]`) which is then equal to `arr[0]` which in turn will decay to `&arr[0][0]`.