# Strange behaviour of arr[] in case when arr is a 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I was learning about 2D arrays and pointer representation of it and all. I ran the following to get the internal working of 2d arrays. I got strange results for the arr2d[0]

```
    int arr2d[2][3]{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    cout<<"&arr2d[0][0] :"<<&arr2d[0][0]<<endl;
    cout<<"(&(arr2d[0])) :"<<(&(arr2d[0]))<<" arr2d[0] :"<<arr2d[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"*(arr2d[0]) :"<< *(arr2d[0])<<" *(&(arr2d[0])) :"<<*(&(arr2d[0]))<<endl;
```

output:

```
&arr2d[0][0] :0x3e6d7ff6c0
(&(arr2d[0])) :0x44efbffbe0 arr2d[0] :0x44efbffbe0
*(arr2d[0]) :1 *(&(arr2d[0])) :0x44efbffbe0
```

How can *(arr2d[0]) have 1 as output, if arr2d[0] is "circularly pointing" itself?
Also apparently pointer arthimetic is not functioning for arr[0], as arr[0]+1 doesn't gets one to arr[1].

I was not expecting the arr[0] to be circularly pointing to itself, I expected it to a pointer to a 1D array of length 3. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56910815/if-a-2d-array-is-not-a-double-pointer-then-why-does-this-happen) tells that this happens but I want to know why how can arr[0] point to itself but at the same time *(arr[0]) gives 1?

Comment: what do you mean with "point to itself" ? The whole array, the first row and the first element all have the same adress

Comment: An array in C++ is merely a sequence of its elements, contiguous in memory. An array of `int[3]` is a sequence of `int[3]` in memory, and `int[3]` is itself a sequence of `int` in memory. Dereferencing removes one layer of that and is fairly similar to just getting the zero'th element to begin with. In fact, in the absence of possible alignment issues and other messy memory details, `int[2][3]` is basically the same thing as `int[6]`.

Comment: details matter, the output of the code you posted does not start with `12345`

Comment: Side note: Many people are taught at an array is a pointer to its first element. This is not true. An array is an array. it simply converts, [decays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay), to a pointer easily and automatically.

Comment: Very related: [What is array to pointer decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay?r=Saves_AllUserSaves)

Comment: This output cannot be produced by this code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: that 12345 is a system generated gibberish output, printed with every file, but I get what youre saying. Shouldn't * (arr) and *(&arr) be giving same value given that arr and &arr have same value in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can `*(arr2d[0])` have 1 as output, if `arr2d[0]` is "circularly pointing" itself?

It's not pointing to itself.  Arrays are not pointers, but like any variable they do have an address, and the address of an array is the same as the address of the first element.  This extends to multidimensional arrays, so `arr2d`, `arr2d[0]`, and `arr2d[0][0]` all have the same address, although their types are different.

> apparently pointer arthimetic is not functioning for `arr[0]`, as `arr[0]+1` doesn't gets one to `arr[1]`.

`arr2d[0]` decays to `&arr2d[0][0]`, so `aarr2drr[0]+1` is `&arr2d[0][0]+1` which is the same as `arr2d[0][1]`.  Had you used the expression `arr2d + 1`, that would be the same as `&arr2d[0] + 1` which gives you `arr2d[1]`

Comment: nitpick "&arr2d, &arr2d[0], and &arr2d[0][0] all have the same address" those are already the addresses, they have "the same value"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Good catch.  Updated.